# Why does the get operation have a runtime of O(1) for an ArrayList, but O(N) for a LinkedList?

Tags: arraylist, linked-list, runtime, big-o

What is the difference between the two runtimes, and how is it achieved? If I could also get an explanation for the runtimes that would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arraylists use arrays, which has indeces, to implement data structures. If you know the index which you're getting the data from, the get will be O(1).

LinkedLIsts use relative references to implement data structures. You inevitably have to traverse the link to get to the one you want. Each link is a passage to another link. Therefore, it's O(n).